# PHP why can't I name my function 'include'?

Tags: php, apache, naming

I'm currently switching my web-application from my local development server to a public one. And I discovered a little bug in my packetManager.php file (which is a little script to help me order my php-packets) For some reason I can't name my function 'include'. Does anyone know why this is and what causes it?

My local development server runs php version 7.1.23 and my public server runs 5.6.39.

When I comment the include function out it gives the expected result: 'It dit not crash' but when I uncomment the function it gives an 500-error. (internal server error) Which suggests that the problem lies before actually executing the code.

```
die("It did not crash");
class _PacketManager {
    public function include() {
        // crashes php
    }   
    public function includePacket() { 
        // works perfectly fine
    }   
}
```

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: Put Examples of your code

Comment: It's because there is already an existing built-in function called `include`

Comment: @JasonKLai  That shouldn't be a problem right? I can just overwrite it,

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php but it's OK as of PHP7 https://3v4l.org/LVfnL

Comment: @ThaNet I've tested it so far and this is the simpelst variant of my code that still contains the bug, I could add more code but that wouldn't solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you @AbraCadaver Now I see why I couldn't use it on my global server, but that begs the question, why doesn't it crash on my local server?

Comment: _As of PHP 7.0.0 these keywords are allowed as property, constant, and method names of classes, interfaces and traits, except that class may not be used as constant name._

Comment: Ah I see, any suggestions how I can keep the function name 'include' and still have the server run PHP < 7? @AbraCadaver Otherwise I'll have to change it everywhere, which is possible but not preferable

Comment: No, unless you can upgrade to 7 you need to rename.

Comment: Oke, thank you very much, I'll see if I can get it to version 7.